# Is there a term for when the moisture on the inside of your nose freezes when breathing in on a very cold day?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

On particularly cold days, the moisture inside of one's nose freezes instantly with every inhalation.  It is a peculiar sensation as if all the hairs inside your nose have been glued together. I was curious if there is a term for this.

My efforts to find this have only revealed useful tips for avoiding frostbite.

My working neologism is 'nasal hoar-frost'.

Comment: I don't think any words will be possible with one's nose blocked like that anyway.

Comment: *Nose freeze* is what we call it, sometimes *snot freeze*. Not to be confused with *snotcicle*, which is when your snot freezes on the outside of your nose.

Comment: I think you want norwegian.stackexchange.com  :-)

Comment: @KitZ.Fox - You definitely speak from experience.

Comment: when its cold, i breathe with my mouth

Comment: Maybe *nasal rime*?

Comment: I saw _snotfrost_ used for this. There is an urbandictionary definition also (both swedish and english): http://tl.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Snorfrost%20%28eng%3A%20Snotfrost%29

Comment: Been living in Minnesota for 41 years and I've never heard a term for it.  There may be localized terms, but I doubt that there's anything with any sort of wide usage.

Comment: +1 Minnow for such an OP of such surpassing strangeness! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Nasal rime** (a neologism, as I’m unaware of an established word/term for this)

> NASAL *adjective*:
>
> 1. of, for, or relating to the nose. "the *nasal* passages"
>
> From Google [**link**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=rime+frost+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=nasal+define&gs_l=hp..0.41l700.0.0.6.4915773...........0.M1w6VOzGtkU&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> RIME *noun*:
>
> 1: frost
>
> 2: an accumulation of granular ice tufts on the windward sides of exposed objects that is formed from supercooled fog or cloud and built out directly against the wind
>
> 3: crust, incrustation
>
> From Merriam-Webster Dictionary [**link**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rime)

Please note: bib beat me to this--by a long shot--so he should be credited, however, I arrived at this formulation independently and didn’t see bib’s comment until I was ready to post. Since no answer has been posted and with acknowledgment to bib ...